# Is it correct "I used to use this pen."?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

I am curious to know if I am writing this sentence grammatically correctly.
I was thinking that using the same verb "**use**" two times in this sentence is grammatically incorrect.

> I used to use this pen.

or

> I used this pen earlier.

Comment: Are you really asking about spelling?

Comment: I want to know if this sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: "I used to use this pen when I was learning italic handwriting at school." (I habitually used it at some period in the past.)

Comment: There's nothing grammatically incorrect about using the word *use* twice in one sentence.  Especially when they mean different things, like they do here.  "I used to (verb)" means I did (verb) as a habit.  What was the verb I did as a habit?  Use something.

Comment: Note that although "used" ***looks*** the same in both examples, they're effectively ***two completely different words*** (they're pronounced completely different, and they have completely different meanings). Also, the sentences containing them have different meanings - they're not just alternative ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: Same spelling but different verbs with different grammar and different meanings (check your dictionary). The first is the aspectual verb "use", the second the transitive verb "use".

Comment: Great question,   After all my years of speaking and writing English, I still must pause for a second after writing *used to use* and ask myself, *Is that right?*  It always is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They are pronounced completely differently? What's the difference? I've never noticed, and I can't find anything in dictionaries.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica "used to" is often fused as "yoozta" or "yooztu"

Comment: While the meanings and pronunciations may be different, it's often better writing style to avoid repeated words in a sentence. But that's style, not grammar.

Comment: That's basically the fusion I described. It happens with other verbs, too: "wanted to" may be slurred as "wan-eh-ta"

Comment: @Barmar: I often see non-native speakers getting confused by "the same" word being used more than once in an utterance with different meanings, but I've never heard anyone suggest it's "poor style" (in either "literature", or any other text, come to that). Context nearly always means that native Anglophhones have no problem parsing and understanding the text, and often they don't even *notice* repetitions that cause problems for nns.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe it's just a personal preference, it feels repetitive to use the same word in close proximity. I'll usually rewrite with a synonym to avoid it.

Comment: @Barmar: That's another slightly *different* characteristic I strongly associate with nns! We get many posts on both ELL and ELU from people (usually nns) asking for "synonyms" of some word, on the grounds that they don't like to repeat the word ***even if it has exactly the same meaning every time***. It's like they can't trust themselves to have chosen the ***best*** word for the context, so they prefer a "scatter gun" approach in hopes that at least *one* variant will hit the spot. But to my mind, that's indicative of a very poor writing style, totally lacking in confidence or clarity.

Comment: @Barmar *"used to" is often fused as "yoozta" or "yooztu"* . Only in spoken english, never in written english unless it is part of a quotation. It also depends on which dialect you mean. In speech I would probably say "yoos't"

Comment: @PeterJennings Of course, I thought it was clear I was responding to the comment asking about the pronunciation difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences are correct.

> I used to use this pen.

This sentence communicates that using a particular pen was a habit you no longer indulge in for whatever reason unknown to the reader.

We use "used to + root form" to indicate habits of the past that are no longer a part of our current pattern of behavior.

> I used this pen earlier.

This sentence communicates that a particular pen's utility was exploited at a concluded point in time, now the past.

Comment: Could you have written the last sentence any more verbose, "this sentence says that you used the pen at some time in the past"

Comment: All those words for the second "definition", and you didn't mention the very powerful implication of ***earlier = recently***, which is very different to the first example (that strongly implies ***some time ago, NOT  recently***). To my mind, this is perhaps the ***main*** reason the two sentences have different meanings.

Comment: @Alexander Jorgensen Note that the aspectual verb is just "used". The "to" is part of the verb that complements it: "I used [to use this pen]" (**not** "I used to [use this pen]")

Comment: Note that the intent of the sentences may depend on which word you emphasize with intonation. "I *used* to use this pen" emphasizes that it was a past habit. "I used to *use* this pen." distinguishes it from other things you now do with the pen ("now I just chew on it.") And "I used to use *this* pen" distinguishes this pen from some other pen.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not entirely sure what is meant in terms of "all those words," but I do appreciate your remarks on the implication of "earlier".  My bad. I chose the word "utility" to suggest that a pen can be used in a number of ways.

Comment: "all those words" was just an alternative to "What @WendyG said" (I agreed with her assertion that your last sentence was a bit verbose). Your idea about "utility" reflecting that a pen can be used in a number of ways is interesting (I could have been using *this* pen to prop up the back of my keyboard for a more convenient typing angle). But maybe I used to use *that* pen as a plaything for my cat. It doesn't really make any difference to OP's question that pens can have multiple uses - that meaning of the word "use = utility" has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But in point of fact use does have a direct relationship to utility in terms of meaning. With regards to that particular sentence being deemed verbose, it should not be assumed that the construction of my sentence was influenced by affectation, as my choice of words was intentional. I was trying to express an idea without more words than needed, particularly given that I was trying to be clear. Regardless, we are good, and I appreciate your remarks, be sure.

Comment: @WendyG. Please refer to the above statement. I appreciate your criticism, be very sure.

Answer (score 1):

So in the your sentence, the meaning of used is not like using comething. The meaning of used is that you were previously doing whatever and now you don't.

> I used to do this, but now I don't.

So when you say

> I used to use my pen

You are saying that you were previously using your pen but don't continue to do so currnently.

The difference between:

> I used to use this pen

> I used this pen earlier

is that the first is more like a habit and you used your pen frequently in the past. If you used a pen once or twice, you would sat I used this pen earlier.

Comment: There's more to it than that--"used to use" means not just that you used it in the past, but that you used it frequently in the past. I wouldn't say I used to use something if I had only ever used it once or twice.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that. I just added it.